# Shopify product.price.liquid Math Filters not displayed correct

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I've added some code in the product.price.liquid to make a simple math formula:

`<span id="extrainfo">
        <span id="perkg">{{ variant.price | times: 100.0 | divided_by: variant.weight | money }}</span>/100g
      </span>`

[Whole Code of the liquid here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TIup.png)

Result: On the Product detail page, the result of the math formula is shown right=> [Detail Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOE45.png), but on the collections page or homepage, there comes "Inf"=> [Collection Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqutT.png)

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you have access to the `variant` object where you are trying to output this price? I mean are you in the `product.variants` loop or have reassigned the `variant` variable?

Comment: Hey, thank your for your answer :-). I'm not sure but if i wouldnt have access to the variant, why is it shown correctly on product detail page but not on other pages because it's the same snippet for showing price on every site where price is visible.

Answer (score 0):

The last `| money` parameter might be confusing. Try like this

```
{% assign variant_price = variant.price | times: 100.0 %}
{% assign variant_price = variant_price | divided_by: variant.weight %}
{% assign variant_price  | money %}
{{ variant_price }}
```